# TCP settings not sticking after reboot (Yosemite)

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, tcp

I'm changing the following settings in the Terminal, and after I reboot, they return to their default values.

```
sysctl net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=1
sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle=20000
sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepinit=20000
sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepintvl=20000
```

Any idea how to make these settings permanent?

Answer (score 2):

Strip the "sysctl " from the front of those lines and add them to /etc/sysctl.conf.

See the sysctl.conf(5) man page.